# htaccess rewrite url to overwrite characters after hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The file 'location-chunk.php' consists of database queries etc. Now, If any user visits 'city-{anything}.html', the htaccess should show him the output of file 'location-chunk.php'. The word 'anything' can contain any character or number. I am trying the following rewrite rule but it is redirecting to the 404 page.

```
    RewriteRule ^city-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ location-chunk.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: "but not getting success" tells nothing about the issue you are having with your htaccess rule. Could you please be a bit specific?

Comment: Yes Starkeen, it is redirecting to the 404 page

Comment: What URI returns the 404 error?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is just redirecting the 404.php page as I have set it.